# Footnote sticking to the end of content instead of the page bottom

Tags: vertical-alignment, footnotes

I added a footnote to my LaTeX document. But, rather than appearing in the bottom of the page it appears right after the content ends in a given page.

[image]

I am using the `\footnote` command -- nothing special. Are there any further settings I should consider?

This occurs when I split my document into chapters where each chapter is in a separate LaTex file and when I include an image in one of the files. Here is a complete demo of this issue: 
Main LateX

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\include{chapter1}

\end{document}
```

and the chapter file:

```
\chapter{One}

This is some content\footnote{hello}. \blindtext{}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
\centering%
\includegraphics[scale=0.55]{DiagramAlbula}
\captionof{figure}{test}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
```

Futher Notice: I am using texLive

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I added a working demo of the issue.

Comment: `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}` should do the necessary. (cf `footmisc` doc, p4, for some provisos)

Comment: I don't get the behaviour by your mwe. So some thing else is going on. Anyway it seems your problem is solved. :-)

Comment: @wasteofspace Can you write an answer, please?

Answer (score 4):

```
 \usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
```

should do the necessary. (cf footmisc doc, p4, for some provisos)

Comment: I have a very similar problem and footmisc does not solve it. NB: a footnote on the title page _does_ appear at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @my2cts you would need to ask a new question (you can reference this one) with a small but complete test document showing the problem

Comment: I found a solution: include 'nofootinbib' in the document class.

Comment: I am using revtex4-2.